# Displaying Black on a Black Background

Tags: print-design, color-theory, black

(First post, yay!)
Im working on a fashion lookbook for print and I'm displaying product colours on a black background, but what can I do for when I need to display black on black? Example:

[image: Example]

As you can see there are 3 colours but the black is not legible on black, what do you reckon I could do to improve visibility without compromising design too much? I cant change the black background FYI. The black dot in the picture isn't quite Black (#000000) its actually #20201f which I thought would help but when we did a test print it was basically invisible.

Comment: By the way, welcome to GDSE!

Comment: Odd. It took me a long time time to figure out what you were talking about as the third circle was perfectly visible to me.

Comment: @Joshua Yeah its visible on desktop but as printers don't have as many colours its basically invisible

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are a couple of things you could do...

Stroke the black:

[image]

Use an outer Glow, this may not work depending on the rest of the design:

[image]

Stroke all of them, this is what I think I would do:

[image]

Comment: Circle B, the master of circles

Comment: There you go! :-)

Comment: Yeah I think i'm gonna go with option 3 that you mentioned, thanks for the advice! +1 :)

Comment: Great, obviously the strokes I did are pretty rough since they are not vector, and I would definitely do like Bakabaka said and make them the same thickness as the line below the circles.

Comment: Do add to the stroke idea, I'd also consider a slightly thicker one at 50% gray.

Comment: Of course, for consistency, you could also glow all of them, but I would also go with the stroke. It looks nicer.

Answer (score 8):

Keep it simple: use a subtle outline on each of the circular swatches. From what I can see, the colour and thickness of the horizontal white line would be great.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your comment, good observation of the stroke.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the capability and the time to experiment, I would try glossy dots on a matte background.

Comment: I second that. I have done it, and it is - when done well - superbly elegant. That would mean gloss on the other coloured dots too.